# Unable to install Minecraft Java Edition (0x89235172)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

I recently got Minecraft through a code but whenever I try to install it, it says:

> We weren't able to install the app (0x89235172).

I've tried reinstalling and restarting my laptop but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some things I have found to work:

1. Sign out and sign in again, make sure date and time, time zone and region are correct
2. Run Windows Store Troubleshooter
3. Use My Library to download the game or app
4. Clear store cache Using wsreset command
5. Reset Store app
6. Restart Windows Update components, start Microsoft Store Install service
7. Update Windows
8. Run these commands
   Ipconfig /flushdns
   Ipconfig /release
   Ipconfig /renew
   netsh winsock reset
   netsh int ip reset
9. Run Powershell command to re-register store
10. Uninstall & Reinstall Store
11. Run DISM Command
    sfc /scannow
    Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
12. Run inetcpl.cpl command
    In Advanced Tab
    Check Use TLS 1.0, 1.1, 1.2 and 1.3
13. Update Windows 10 or 11 using media creation tool